# How can I change 10k commit messages with a pattern

Tags: git, sed

I want to rewrite all of my commit messages in a repository. The repository is large and has over 10k commits.  I want to replace all text that matches one of the following patterns with `Issue`

```
"(?i)conn-\d{1,4}[abcdi]"
"(?i)conn-\d{1,4}"
"(?i)connect-\d{1,4}"
"(?i)gateway-\d{1,4}[ab]"
"(?i)gateway-\d{1,4}"
```

I attempted to use the top answer to ["What's the fastest way to edit hundreds of Git commit messages?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332551/whats-the-fastest-way-to-edit-hundreds-of-git-commit-messages/39507441#comment66915767_39507441) But using `git format-patch -10000` then editing all the patches then doing `git am *.patch` I get tons of errors `error: file/name.txt does not not exist in index the file/name.txt`.

I know I can do it with `git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "sed 's/<old>/<new>/'"` But how can I do it with all the patterns in one go rather than one time for each pattern? Each time I execute `git filter-branch` the process takes 1 hour. So I would ideally just execute it one time.

Comment: You can easily match multiple patterns in `sed`; if you want to use these Perl regexes (which are not supported by any `sed` dialect out of the box), execution will probably be somewhat slower, but `perl -pe 's/conn-\d{1,4}[abcdi]?|connect-\d{1,4}|gateway-\d{1,4}[ab]?/Issue/i'` would do that.

Comment: Or if it gets too complicated, surely you can do `git filter-branch -f --msg-filter /path/to/filter_script.sh` then in filter_script.sh you can read stdin, modify it as you want, and echo it out.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands

Comment: @Mort is there a stack over flow question that answers how to create a script with stdin?