# Git automate rewording git commit messages on branch

Tags: typescript, git, automation, version-control

Is there any way that I can run a script on a branch to reword all commit messages that contains a specific substring in the commit message. Say I have a [repo like this](https://github.com/Norfeldt/git-history-example):

[image]

Then I would like to reword all the commit messages (on `mybranch` and not `main`) that starts with  `build version` and append the suffix  `⚠️ (rebased since)`.

Can I do it via a git command, bash script or event typescript script (triggered by ts-node or deno)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458610/6309) in order to modify commit messages.

See "[Updating commit/tag messages](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_updating_commit_tag_messages)" for a simple solution

> If you want to modify commit or tag messages, you can do so with the same syntax as --replace-text, explained above. For example, with a file named expressions.txt containing
>
> ```
>  build version==> build version ⚠️ (rebased since)
> ```
>
> then running
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --replace-message expressions.txt
> ```

But that will not append `⚠️ (rebased since)` at the end of your commit message though.

If you need it at the end, then you need a [`commit-callback`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS), as done in the [answer I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458610/6309).

Answer (score 0):

a)

- make an empty commit with a new message
- squash it into old commit

b)

- find out the needed depth
- rebase it on itself interactively `git rebase -i HEAD~3`
- change reworded commits to `exec 310154e tsx reword-commit.ts`
- make `reword-commit.ts` rewrite the file with commit message
- you can run that from TS via `execa` ow any outher ts shell launcher
  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Answer (score 0):

inspired from @VonC I came to this script:

(`brew install git-filter-repo` is needed)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Create a temporary file to store the commit messages
temp_file=$(mktemp)

main_head_hash=$(git rev-parse main)
suffix="⚠️ rebased since!"
# Use git log to retrieve the commit messages and store them in the temporary file
git log --pretty=format:%s $main_head_hash.. | grep -v $suffix | grep ' build version' > $temp_file

# Create a file to store the replacements
echo > replacements.txt

# Iterate over the commit messages in the temporary file
while read commit_message; do
  # Print the replacement message to the replacements.txt file
  echo "$commit_message==>$commit_message $suffix" >> replacements.txt
done < $temp_file


# ⚠️⚠️ Rewriting history ⚠️⚠️
git filter-repo --replace-message replacements.txt --force

# Remove the temporary files
rm $temp_file
rm replacements.txt
```

(The script was made with help of chatGPT - giving it clear instructions on what steps to write a script for. I'm aware of the [temp. ban policy of chatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) and hope this does not appear as an policy violation since the answer is not solely based of it, but derived from a conversation with trail and error - the script is verified to work and I hope that it will help others)

[image]

Comment: Nicely done, that should work indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: thank you @VonC for telling me about `filter-repo`