# Git move non-feature-related commits to another branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-repo

Working on feature branch and doing some non-feature-related work in commit `D`. Now I want to move (not just cherrypick) that commit to another refactor branch.

```
    C - D (HEAD w. uncommitted changes) [feature branch]
   /
A-B [main branch]
   \
    D [refactor branch]
```

Currently I know of two ways of doing this:

### Option 1 with interactive rebasing

1. `git checkout -b refactor` (and perhaps stash or WIP the uncommitted changes)
2. `git rebase -i main` and delete all the **feature** related commits
3. `git switch feature`

### Option 2 with cherry-picking

1. `git switch main` (perhaps stash or WIP the uncommitted changes before)
2. `git checkout -b refactor`
3. `git cherry-pick <D hash>`
4. `git switch feature`
5. `git rebase refactor`

Are there any other good ways for doing it?

It would be handy if there was a to commit to another branch than the current checkout (HEAD).

Or if there would a way to have the cherry-pick also remove the commit from the feature branch.

---

(I'm wondering if [git-filter-repo could be used to automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887239/git-automate-rewording-git-commit-messages-on-branch) step 2 (`git rebase -i main` and delete all the **feature** related commits) in option 1 by saying that it should remove all similar commits that can be found on the refactor branch.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a commit from a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-do-i-delete-a-commit-from-a-branch)

Comment: Wouldn't that reset the all commits down to the commit I want to remove - instead of specifically removing only that single commit. Remember I might have a WIP commit that I don't wanna lose.

Answer (score 1):

Your second way supposes your feature branch would need/require refactor, since you are rebasing `feature` on top of `refactor`.

If that is not the case, using the cheery-pick option, you can remove the commit from the feature branch by `git reset --hard C` (after a git stash, in case you have other work in progress not yet committed)

But it is true a cherry-pick does not remove a commit from its source branch. It only duplicates it.